# libgdx - scene2d.ui label height

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Why is this happening?

```
TextBounds tBounds1 = game.font.getWrappedBounds("blah\nblah\nblah", 300);
System.out.println(""+tBounds1.height); // outputs 79.0001
TextBounds tBounds2 = game.font.getWrappedBounds("blah", 300);
System.out.println(""+tBounds1.height); // outputs 20.00002
```

So the variable `tBounds1` has changed simply by calling `getWrappedBounds()` on another variable. How is this even...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that tBounds1 and tBounds2 are pointing to the same object.

If you try to check them, it is happening that **areSame** below it is **true**

```
boolean areSame = tBounds1 == tBounds2;
```

so **tBounds1** and **tBounds2** are pointing to the same object. The **getWrappedBounds** method is called by:

```
public TextBounds getWrappedBounds (CharSequence str, float wrapWidth) {
    return getWrappedBounds(str, wrapWidth, cache.getBounds());
}
```

Not the cache.getBounds. The **cache** is created at start when creating the BitmapFont

```
private final BitmapFontCache cache;
```

so the **cache** is a property of the current font and therefore when something is changed there, it is also propagated.

the **getWrappedBounds** method calls also the other method:

```
public TextBounds getWrappedBounds (CharSequence str, float wrapWidth, TextBounds textBounds) {
    // Just removed the lines here
    textBounds.width = maxWidth;
    textBounds.height = data.capHeight + (numLines - 1) * data.lineHeight;
    return **textBounds**;
}
```

This method at the end is changing the BitmapFontCache cache object.

So if you want to calculate the height for 2 different strings, you can assign it to primitive types:

```
float height1 = font.getWrappedBounds("blah\nblah\nblah", 300);
float height2 = font.getWrappedBounds("blah", 300);
```

or if you need a full BitmapFont.TextBounds object, this:

```
BitmapFont.TextBounds tBounds1 = new BitmapFont.TextBounds(font.getWrappedBounds("blah\nblah\nblah", 300));
BitmapFont.TextBounds tBounds2 = new BitmapFont.TextBounds(font.getWrappedBounds("blah", 300));
```

In this way you wound ensure that tBounds1 and tBounds2 are pointing to different objects.

Comment: Yeah, I went with assigning to primitive types, but I wasted an hour trying to find the problem first. Oh well